# Getting android installation error in emulator with android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-service, android-logcat

I am trying to build a simple android app with a single activity with two buttons on it with two button with `setOnClickListener` methods.But while trying to run the android project in emulator,the app is failing to get installed stating

```
[2013-03-25 13:03:38 - MyHapiSample] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED
[2013-03-25 13:03:38 - MyHapiSample] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-03-25 13:03:38 - MyHapiSample] Launch canceled!
```

I am getting the following error in the logcat view

```
03-25 11:52:20.430: D/ExchangeService(630): Received deviceId from Email app: null
03-25 11:52:20.430: D/ExchangeService(630): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and   retrying
03-25 11:52:22.543: W/Trace(429): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 11:52:22.564: W/Trace(429): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 11:52:25.503: W/Trace(630): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 11:52:25.513: D/ExchangeService(630): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
03-25 11:52:25.523: W/Trace(630): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 11:52:25.523: W/Trace(630): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 11:52:25.523: D/ExchangeService(630): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand,   startingUp = false, running = false
03-25 11:52:25.533: W/ActivityManager(274): Unable to start service Intent {  act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
03-25 11:52:25.533: D/ExchangeService(630): !!! Email application not found; stopping  self
03-25 11:52:25.544: W/Trace(630): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 11:52:25.544: W/Trace(630): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 11:52:25.544: D/ExchangeService(630): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
03-25 11:52:25.564: W/ActivityManager(274): Unable to start service Intent {  act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
03-25 11:52:25.564: W/Trace(630): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 11:52:25.573: W/Trace(630): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 11:52:25.584: W/Trace(630): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630): Service  com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cecfc8 that was originally bound here
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cecfc8 that was originally bound here
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at  android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-25 11:52:25.593: E/ActivityThread(630):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630): null
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service  com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection  com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cecfc8 that was originally  bound here

03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-25 11:52:25.615: E/StrictMode(630):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-25 11:52:25.615: W/ActivityManager(274): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@41649e50
```

I am not getting what might be the error.My emulator is running fine for other apps.
I am using **Android API 4.2(17)**

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

**Edit 1**

Here follows my code consisting a single activity.

```
package com.example.myhapisample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;

import ca.uhn.hl7v2.DefaultHapiContext;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.HL7Exception;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.HapiContext;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.Message;


import ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.EncodingNotSupportedException;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.Parser;

import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v24.message.ADT_A01;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v24.segment.MSH;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v24.segment.PID;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v24.segment.PV1;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v24.segment.PV2;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v24.segment.NK1;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v24.segment.OBX;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v24.datatype.PN;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v24.datatype.XPN;

public class MyHapiSampleActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_hapi_sample);

    System.out.println("HapiSample App screen launched");
     Button ParseMsgbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

     Button GenerateMsgbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        ParseMsgbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



             String msg = "MSH|^~\\&|HIS|RIH|EKG|EKG|199904140038||ADT^A01||P|2.2\r"
                          + "PID|0001|00009874|00001122|A00977|SMITH^JOHN^M|MOM|19581119|F|NOTREAL^LINDA^M|C|564 SPRING ST^^NEEDHAM^MA^02494^US|0002|(818)565-1551|(425)828-3344|E|S|C|0000444444|252-00-4414||||SA|||SA||||NONE|V1|0001|I|D.ER^50A^M110^01|ER|P00055|11B^M011^02|070615^BATMAN^GEORGE^L|555888^NOTREAL^BOB^K^DR^MD|777889^NOTREAL^SAM^T^DR^MD^PHD|ER|D.WT^1A^M010^01|||ER|AMB|02|070615^NOTREAL^BILL^L|ER|000001916994|D||||||||||||||||GDD|WA|NORM|02|O|02|E.IN^02D^M090^01|E.IN^01D^M080^01|199904072124|199904101200|199904101200||||5555112333|||666097^NOTREAL^MANNY^P\r"
                        + "NK1|0222555|NOTREAL^JAMES^R|FA|STREET^OTHER STREET^CITY^ST^55566|(222)111-3333|(888)999-0000|||||||ORGANIZATION\r"
                        + "PV1|0001|I|D.ER^1F^M950^01|ER|P000998|11B^M011^02|070615^BATMAN^GEORGE^L|555888^OKNEL^BOB^K^DR^MD|777889^NOTREAL^SAM^T^DR^MD^PHD|ER|D.WT^1A^M010^01|||ER|AMB|02|070615^VOICE^BILL^L|ER|000001916994|D||||||||||||||||GDD|WA|NORM|02|O|02|E.IN^02D^M090^01|E.IN^01D^M080^01|199904072124|199904101200|||||5555112333|||666097^DNOTREAL^MANNY^P\r"
                         + "PV2|||0112^TESTING|55555^PATIENT IS NORMAL|NONE|||19990225|19990226|1|1|TESTING|555888^NOTREAL^BOB^K^DR^MD||||||||||PROD^003^099|02|ER||NONE|19990225|19990223|19990316|NONE\r"
                          + "AL1||SEV|001^POLLEN\r"
                        + "GT1||0222PL|NOTREAL^BOB^B||STREET^OTHER STREET^CITY^ST^77787|(444)999-3333|(222)777-5555||||MO|111-33-5555||||NOTREAL GILL N|STREET^OTHER STREET^CITY^ST^99999|(111)222-3333\r"
                         + "IN1||022254P|4558PD|BLUE CROSS|STREET^OTHER STREET^CITY^ST^00990||(333)333-6666||221K|LENIX|||19980515|19990515|||PATIENT01 TEST D||||||||||||||||||02LL|022LP554";


                  * The HapiContext holds all configuration and provides factory methods for obtaining
                 * all sorts of HAPI objects, e.g. parsers. 

                   HapiContext context = new DefaultHapiContext();
                   System.out.println("HapiSample App Hapi Context created");

                  * A Parser is used to convert between string representations of messages and instances of
                * HAPI's "Message" object. In this case, we are using a "GenericParser", which is able to
                * handle both XML and ER7 (pipe & hat) encodings.

                  Parser p = context.getGenericParser();

                         Message hapiMsg;
                    try {
                        // The parse method performs the actual parsing
                        hapiMsg = p.parse(msg);
               } catch (EncodingNotSupportedException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                        return;
                     } catch (HL7Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                       return;
                     }


                     * This message was an ADT^A01 is an HL7 data type consisting of several components1, so we
                           * will cast it as such. The ADT_A01 class extends from Message, providing specialized
                          * accessors for ADT^A01's segments.
                          * 
                           * HAPI provides several versions of the ADT_A01 class, each in a different package (note
                           * the import statement above) corresponding to the HL7 version for the message.

                          ADT_A01 adtMsg = (ADT_A01)hapiMsg;

                     MSH msh = adtMsg.getMSH();

                    // Retrieve some data from the MSH segment
                         String msgType = msh.getMessageType().getMessageType().getValue();
                  String msgTrigger = msh.getMessageType().getTriggerEvent().getValue();
                  Log.e("Upto this working fine", "HL7 Message parsed properly");
                        // Prints "ADT A01"
                         System.out.println(msgType + " " + msgTrigger);


                          * Now let's retrieve the patient's name from the parsed message. 
                      * 
                          * PN is an HL7 data type consisting of several components, such as 
                     * family name, given name, etc. 

                         //XPN patientName = adtMsg.getPID().getPatientName();
                         //String obxObs=adtMsg.getOBX().getObservationValue().toString();
                         //System.out.println(obxObs);

                         // Prints "SMITH"
                       // String familyName = patientName.getFamilyName().getValue();
                       // System.out.println(familyName);


        }
    });

     GenerateMsgbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View view){

             generateHL7Message();

         }
     });

}
@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_my_hapi_sample, menu);
    return true;
}

void generateHL7Message(){
    try{
    ADT_A01 adt = new ADT_A01();
    adt.initQuickstart("ADT", "A01", "P");

// Populate the MSH Segment
  MSH mshSegment = adt.getMSH();
  mshSegment.getSendingApplication().getNamespaceID().setValue("TestSendingSystem");
    mshSegment.getSequenceNumber().setValue("123");

    // Populate the PID Segment
PID pid = adt.getPID(); 
pid.getPatientName(0).getFamilyName().getSurname().setValue("Miki");
pid.getPatientName(0).getGivenName().setValue("Daniel");
   pid.getPatientIdentifierList(0).getID().setValue("123456");
pid.getPid23_BirthPlace().setValue("Ontario");

PV1 pv1=adt.getPV1();
pv1.getAdmissionType().setValue("Above normal");
pv1.getPatientClass().setValue("E");
pv1.getPatientType().setValue("Old Patient");   
pv1.getBedStatus().setValue("Occupied");
pv1.getDietType().getIdentifier().setValue("1");
pv1.getDietType().getText().setValue("Prescription");
pv1.getDietType().getCe3_NameOfCodingSystem().setValue("Internal");

PV2 pv2=adt.getPV2();
pv2.getAdmitReason().getIdentifier().setValue("P01");
pv2.getAdmitReason().getCe2_Text().setValue("Treatment");
pv2.getVisitDescription().setValue("FirstVisitToClinic");
pv2.getPreviousTreatmentDate().setYearMonthDayPrecision(2004, 11, 6);
pv2.getPatientConditionCode().getIdentifier().setValue("1");
pv2.getPatientConditionCode().getCe2_Text().setValue("Improving");
pv2.getPatientStatusEffectiveDate().setValue("");
pv2.getModeOfArrivalCode().getCe1_Identifier().setValue("67709");
pv2.getModeOfArrivalCode().getCe2_Text().setValue("ambulance");

NK1 nk1=adt.getNK1();
nk1.getNk127_Nationality().getCe2_Text().setValue("Indian");
nk1.getRelationship().getIdentifier().setValue("1");
nk1.getRelationship().getText().setValue("Brother");

OBX obx=adt.getOBX();
   obx.getDateTimeOfTheAnalysis().getTimeOfAnEvent().setDateMinutePrecision(2013,02,11,9,36);
obx.getObx3_ObservationIdentifier().getCe1_Identifier().setValue("1");
obx.getObx3_ObservationIdentifier().getText().setValue("Blood Pressure");
obx.getObx3_ObservationIdentifier().getAlternateText().setValue("Normal");
obx.getObx11_ObservationResultStatus().setValue("Result updated");
 /*
        * In a real situation, of course, many more segments and fields would be  populated
     */

// Now, let's encode the message and look at the output
 HapiContext context = new DefaultHapiContext();
    Parser parser = context.getPipeParser();
 String encodedMessage = parser.encode(adt);
 System.out.println("Printing HL7 Encoded Message:\n\n\n");
 System.out.println(encodedMessage);
 String outputHL7="\n\n\n\n\n\n"+encodedMessage;
    }
     catch(HL7Exception ex){
         Log.e("HL7 error", "HL7 exception");
     } 
     catch(IOException e){
         Log.e("IOException error", "msg");
     }
    }
}
```

I am using several jars provided by HAPI library to parse and generate HL7 data.Earlier the app was working fine in emulator with these jars with one button and `setOnClickListener`. But I have been getting error after adding another button and its `setOnClickListener` method.

I am clueless regarding this error coming.

Please help.

Comment: it is better if you could show your code. this error looks unrelated to your application tho.

Comment: @bluebrain I have uploaded my code.Please have a look.I am using several third party jars to parse and generate HL7 data

Comment: I dont see relation between HAPI and the error you get, but since `generateHL7Message()` method catches an IOException, it might be trying to do something related to network. Network connection on main thread is forbidden. You might try an AsyncTask in order handle network things and do GUI updates on `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: @ bluebrain  I have put my `generateHL7Message()` function's content in an Asynctask class.But I am having the same error.

Not getting the issue which is causing the error.  :(

Comment: @bluebrain My app is running with the AsyncTask as suggested by you.Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: you should accept the answer below by putting a tick on it. ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was solved when I performed  `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` and recreated my device emulator.I also had to shuffle some of the third party jars that I am using for my app.I think the error had something to do with the memory leak of the android emulator during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see relation between `HAPI` and the error you get, but since `generateHL7Message()` method catches an `IOException`, it might be trying to do something related to network. Network connection on main thread is forbidden. You might try an `AsyncTask` in order handle network things and do GUI updates on `onPostExecute` method.